# Which is better HBASE or Neo4j

Tags: hadoop, hbase, neo4j

Hi guys i am analyzing few things for doing a Proof of concept. I want to convert a Employee payroll database to Nosql. Which is better to use HBASE or Neo4j?
Or if you guys have any other suggestion please tell me

Comment: Your question is like asking "Which are better, cars or spoons?" Neo4j is a specialized graph database. It stores nodes connected by edges. HBase is a more general purpose database. They are very, very different.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For your task at hand (Payroll) and of these two choices i would recommend you to go with Neo4j.

HBase is for truly big datasets (hundreds of gigabytes / terabytes). Payroll dataset is tiny.

Hbase is not an actual database. It's a data storage. You will have to manually code and navigate links between entities, enforce foreign keys, transactions etc.

Hbase is geared more towards batch processing of large volumes of not structured data rather than OLTP (what you need for Payroll).

Comment: +1 Neo4j can be embedded in your Java application so you do not need a separate database during development of your prototype.

Answer (score 0):

'Analytics' is a pretty broad term. If you want to analyze relationships, or discover information via relationships Neo would be good. Hbase is typically used with Hadoop for doing big data analytics, and where you know the relationship between data but want to analyze large tables of data. But I would think you need to understand both of the technologies a little better before going forward, they're not in the same category.